# alphanumeric sorting in LWC Javascript is not working properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

Alphanumeric sorting in LWC Javascript is not working properly. Below is the code snippet from component library(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example).

Code snippet

```
sortBy(field, reverse, primer) {
        const key = primer
            ? function (x) {
                  return primer(x[field]);
              }
            : function (x) {
                  return x[field];
              };

        return function (a, b) {
            a = key(a);
            b = key(b);
            return reverse * ((a > b) - (b > a));
        };
    }

    onHandleSort(event) {
        const { fieldName: sortedBy, sortDirection } = event.detail;
        const cloneData = [...this.data];

        cloneData.sort(this.sortBy(sortedBy, sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1 : -1));
        this.data = cloneData;
        this.sortDirection = sortDirection;
        this.sortedBy = sortedBy;
    }
```

input = ["Test 1", "Test 2","Test 22","Test 14" ];

I need the output as ["Test 1", "Test 2",""Test 14" , "Test 22" ].

But if I use the above code I am getting ["Test 1","Test 14","Test 2","Test 22"].

Comment: This is doing lexicographic order, as expected. You would have to split the string into parts and convert the number string part into a number.

Comment: @Phil - do you have a code snippet of it?

Comment: Harry, if all your values are of the form *Sometext Numbers* this is simple, but if not then it is likely there is no simple solution.